# How to synchronise a code block in JSR223 Post Processor component in the global scope

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I want to ensure a code block within a JSR223 Post Processor is executed by only one thread at a time. The JSR223 Post Processor is placed just below the Test Plan component to ensure it is shared with all the samplers.

I have tried with following to check if synchronization works as expected

```
synchronized (this){
    def count=props.get("count").toInteger()
    count+=1
    props.put("count",count.toString())
    log.info(" ==== Current count is ${count}   ${__threadNum}  ${vars.get('__jm__TG__idx')}=== ")    
    //different code to be used within this block

}
```

I have noted duplicates (i.e. duplicate `count` values)

Answer (score 1):

1. `props` is a global object so when multiple threads are writing into it the previous value is getting overwritten
2. When you're inlining [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like `${__threadNum}` into Groovy scripts only first value is getting cached and used in the subsequent iterations
3. Each thread is executing JSR223 test elements separately, `sychronized` keyword doesn't act as you expect

So the options are in:

1. Either convert your JSR223 PreProcessor into [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and put it under [Critical Section Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller) (however it will mean "no concurrency"
2. Or go for [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/)

Comment: JSR223 Sampler with a critical section controller  is not a solution in my use-case as  I need to execute the code after every sampler. Solution has use a post processor. I am trying to use Inter-Thread Communication plugin. It worked well with a simple string.

Answer (score 0):

You may include JSR Sampler in [Critical Section Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller) to ensure it's synchronized on JVM level

> ensures that its children elements (samplers/controllers, etc.) will be executed by only one thread as a named lock will be taken before executing children of controller.

> Critical Section Controller takes locks only within one JVM, so if using Distributed testing ensure your use case does not rely on all threads of all JVMs blocking.

Comment: JSR223 Sampler with a critical section controller is not a solution in my use-case as I need to execute the code after every sampler. Solution has use a post processor. I am trying to use Inter-Thread Communication plugin. It worked well with a simple string.